# ClassNotFoundException in servlet project

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

I am getting ClassNotFoundException for the class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver that is present in the ojbc14.jar file. I have found some answer for this question but non of the solution worked.
My project structure is below.

[image]

some suggested to added the ojdbc14.jar file by
right click on project -> build path --> CONFIGURE BUILD PATH --> add external jar .  I have done that but still getting the error in the server window in eclipse.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1854)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259)
at com.ars.util.DBConnection.getCon(DBConnection.java:20)
at com.ars.dao.UserLoginDAO.checkUserLoginDetails(UserLoginDAO.java:18)
at com.ars.handler.UserLoginHandler.doPost(UserLoginHandler.java:53)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:411)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at com.ars.controller.ARSController.doPost(ARSController.java:110)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

when I open the ojdbc14.jar file from the package explorer. I get the below path.
[image]

how to resolve the issue can anyone please help.

Comment: try clean prject and then build the project.

Comment: Why are you using an ancient version of the Oracle JDBC driver, ojdbc14.jar is for Java 1.4 which has been end of life for ages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Libraries (like the `ojdbc14.jar`) need to be placed into the directory `WEB-INF/lib` inside your WAR. The provided screenshot shows that you placed your library into the directory `WEB-INF` (note the missing `lib`).

Alternatively, you can place libraries that might be shared among several web applicatons into the directory `<tomcat>/lib`. This is the preferred way for JDBC driver libraries.

Comment: Alternative option is helpful..:)

Answer (score 0):

Open your war (or directory that you are deploying), and check if this file is present in `WEB-INF/lib` directory. If not, you have to add it there.

Second solution would be to put it inside your application server lib directory. For example `{tomcatHomeDir}/lib`. Second approatch has one advantage: your application will have smaller (thinner) war file. On the other hand deploying multiple applications on same server, that are using different oracle libraries can be troublesone.